# How to disable email notifications in bluemix devops services track & plan

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, continuous-delivery

Working with the 'Track & Plan' feature of the IBM Bluemix DevOps Services generates a lot of email notifications to my co-workers and me. For example, notifications are sent out for each work item creation, modification or assignment. As the number of such mails is overwhelming, I would like to deactivate them.

If I had full access to the underlying RTC instance I would go about this as outlined in the [RTC Knowledge Center - Configuring notifications in the web client](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCP65_6.0.3/com.ibm.team.workitem.doc/topics/t_configuring_notifications_web.html).

So far I haven't been able to find a comparable configuration page in the version hosted on DevOps Services. Also, the Bluemix DevOps Services Documentation (e.g. [Track and plan](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/trackplan/)) didn't yield any hints in that direction.

Is there a way to disable these notifications either completely or at least partly? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable email notifications by following the instructions here:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/185255/configuring-track-plan-email-notifications.html

> 1. Find your name on a full page workitem and click on it (could be in created by, subscribed, mentioned in a comment, ...)
> 2. You'll land in a page that has your profile and some license information...ignore that. Take the URL from the browser window and paste it into a text editor or some text buffer somewhere. e.g. https://hub.jazz.net/jts08/admin#action=com.ibm.team.repository.viewUserProfile⁢emId=_yyeAwKGKEeSa6LqyswPPCA
> 3. Go back to the Track&Plan view click on "Track & Plan" drop down and select the "Project Dashboard". You should now have a URL that looks like: https://hub.jazz.net/ccm08/web/projects/dleroux%20%7C%20TestNewSprint#action=com.ibm.team.dashboard.viewDashboard
> 4. Take the action portion from URL in 2 and replace the action portion of the url in 3 giving you something like: https://hub.jazz.net/ccm08/web/projects/dleroux%20%7C%20TestNewSprint#action=com.ibm.team.repository.viewUserProfile⁢emId=_yyeAwKGKEeSa6LqyswPPCA
> 5. Navigate to the URL...select "Mail configuration"